# How to import different products on different rails pages using Spree

Tags: ruby-on-rails, e-commerce, spree

I am trying to setup a spree store for a band using a template like Unify. I installed spree static content to render static pages. So my question is how do I access the products in different pages of the site? Such as if in the home page I want to have a slider showing featured products, or products by categories (albums, posters, shirts etc.) Then have a merch page listing merch only related products. Maybe on the blog to have a side bar with relevant products or something. How do I give the whole site access to the @products. Thanks

Comment: You could try https://github.com/spree/demo
https://www.google.co.in/search?q=spree+for+ecommerce+demo&oq=spree+for+ecommerce+demo&aqs=chrome..69i57j0.6151j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

For more info.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this piece of code to your controller

`@searcher = build_searcher(params.merge(include_images: true))
@products = @searcher.retrieve_products`

Check https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/master/frontend/app/controllers/spree/home_controller.rb#L7 fore reference